# Types of Tables in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have searched for types of tables in sql, but I didn't understand those answers what I get. Please help me by providing answer.

Comment: You what to know what each type of object does? or?

Comment: If you just want to know the types of tables they are: normal, temporary (transaction), temporary (session), external and indexed organized.

Comment: thanks @DSF  for your answer...can you please give me some simple explanation when we use each type..how does it works..Thanks again .

Comment: You can find that for yourself with Google :)

Answer (score 3):

Oracle supports 4 types of tables based on how data is organized in storage:

Ordinary (heap-organized) table

•A basic, general purpose table
 
•Data is stored as an unordered collection (heap)

Clustered table

•A part of a cluster
 
•Cluster: A cluster is a group of tables that share the same data blocks as they share common columns and are often used together.

Index-organized table

•Data is stored in a B-tree index structure in a primary key sorted manner. 
•Each index entry in the B-tree stores the non-key column values as well.

Partitioned table

•Data is broken down into smaller, more manageable pieces called partitions or sub-partitions.
 
•Each partition can be managed individually
 
•Each partition can operate independently

Read more in the [source](http://www.careerride.com/Oracle-types-of-tables-supported.aspx)